# Why does ZIO not log uncaught exceptions?

Tags: scala, zio

```
def someEndpoint(): Task[Unit] = ZIO.from { 
   throw new RuntimeException("badness happened") 
}
```

This returns a proper failed Task, that can be handled downstream

```
def badEndpoint(): Task[Unit] = ZIO.succeed { 
   throw new RuntimeException("badness")
}
```

This does not ... which is kinda understandable (albeit only a little bit): you asked it to succeed, so it did (but not really) ...
But my question is where does the exception go? In every other framework I have worked with in the past, uncaught exceptions get logged somewhere at the top (or bottom, depending on how you look at it) of the stack. But with ZIO (zio http specifically), there seems to be no feedback. A 500 is returned to the client, but I cannot see anything in the log possibly pointing to the cause.

I am wondering if there it is a general problem with ZIO or if something is just missing in my configuration?

Comment: You have two types of errors. The ones you expect and the ones you don't. You can model your function to return a value or an expected error. A non expected one should interrupt the app and shutdown or try to recover from the failure doing something. Using a `succeed` you are saying that the function doesn't expect any error. [zio http error handling](https://zio.dev/zio-http/dsl/http/#error-handling) shows how to do it. It's not so different from [handling errors in zio](https://zio.dev/overview/handling-errors/)